# Get value multidimensional array and combine product group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a multidimensional array using a csv file.
I get the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product
            [1] => Price
            [2] => Quantity
            [3] => Date
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Teddybear
            [1] => 3.789,33
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2018-08-14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Teddybear
            [1] => 2.702,17
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2018-02-17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Table
            [1] => 2.932,29
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 2018-10-09
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lamp
            [1] => 671,70
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2018-12-11
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Teddybear
            [1] => 481,21
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2018-03-24
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Table
            [1] => 456,52
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2018-05-14
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chair
            [1] => 2.960,20
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2018-06-20
        )

    [8] => 
)
```

I need to create a json file, but before that, I need to count al products and turnover per month

I'm a novice / junior PHP developer and I'm more specialized in WordPress, so forgive me for my bad code and/or bad practices. I'm here to learn.

I really don't know how to select for example all the Teddybears. I know I could do `$csv[1][1];` to select turnover for the first Tedybear.

Comment: well to get you started your going to need a for loop, most likely a foreach loop. Then and if statement to select out the data you are looking for. I would start with that and get an idea of how the logic works. Then you can transition to using a built in function like `array_count_values` [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: You shouldn't put the header line in the array.

Comment: It would be easier if you made this an array of associative arrays, like `[["product' => "Teddybear", "price" => 3789.33, "quantity" => 2, "date" => "2018-08-14"], ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here there should be everything you need, I did 3 functions that you can chain together to get what you need, like in the example

```
$data=[
    ["Product","Price","Quantity","Date"], // <-- if you want to remove the header remove all the lines with this symbol *
    ["Teddybear",3789.33,2,"2018-08-14"],
    ["Teddybear",2702.17,1,"2018-02-17"],
    ["Table",2932.29,5,"2018-10-09"],
    ["Lamp",671.70,3,"2018-12-11"],
    ["Teddybear",481.21,3,"2018-03-24"],
    ["Table",45.52,3,"2018-05-14"],
    ["Chair",2960.20,2,"2018-06-20"]
];


function WhereFromColum($data,$colum,$equal){
    $ret=[];
    array_push($ret,$data[0]);  // *
    $colum = is_numeric($colum)?$colum:array_search($colum,$data[0]);
    for($i=1/* 0 if you remove the header to data*/;$i!=count($data);$i++)
        if ($data[$i][$colum]==$equal) 
            array_push($ret,$data[$i]);
    return $ret;
}

function CountFromColum($data,$colum){
    $ret=0;
    $colum = is_numeric($colum)?$colum:array_search($colum,$data[0]);
    for($i=1/* 0 if you remove the header to data*/;$i!=count($data);$i++)
        $ret+=$data[$i][$colum];
    return $ret;
}

function WhereFromColumData($data,$colum,$min,$max){
    $contractDateBegin = new DateTime($min);
    $contractDateEnd  = new DateTime($max);
    $ret=[];
    array_push($ret,$data[0]);  // *
    $colum = is_numeric($colum)?$colum:array_search($colum,$data[0]);
    for($i=1/* 0 if you remove the header to data*/;$i!=count($data);$i++){
        $paymentDate = new DateTime($data[$i][$colum]);
        if ($paymentDate->getTimestamp() > $contractDateBegin->getTimestamp() && 
            $paymentDate->getTimestamp() < $contractDateEnd->getTimestamp())
            array_push($ret,$data[$i]);
    }
    return $ret;
}


var_dump(WhereFromColum($data,"Product","Teddybear")); // get all Teddybear's Product
var_dump(CountFromColum($data,"Quantity")); // get all Quantity
var_dump(CountFromColum(WhereFromColum($data,"Product","Teddybear"),"Quantity"));  // get all Quantity of Teddybear's Product
var_dump(WhereFromColumData($data,"Date","2018-08-01","2018-12-01")); // get all between 2018-08-01 and 2018-12-01
var_dump(WhereFromColumData(WhereFromColum($data,"Product","Teddybear"),"Date","2018-08-01","2018-12-01")); // get all Teddybear's Product between 2018-08-01 and 2018-12-01
```

usually I don't usually write code but explain how to do it but in your case it was too complex so please kindly read the three functions carefully and try to understand how they work, ps if you want to improve your skils in php I suggest you play a with these functions and modify them to fit what you need best. when you understand how they work you can also create another one with the same logic of nesting that allows you to make much more advanced filters.